# How to know when client has changed the playback time?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Using the timeupdate event you know the current time position of a playback, and is fired continuously until it pauses or ends. What is the event to know when the client has changed the time manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `seeking` and `seeked` events. Both events fire when the time is changed separately from the regular playing time progression. This can happen either by setting the `currentTime` property on the video/audio element in a script or by clicking or dragging on the timeline in player controls.

`seeking` fires immediately when the `currentTime` value changes. `seeked` fires after that, once the new frame at the destination time is loaded and the "seek" operation is done.